# Can the Von-Mangoldt function and the Chebyshev function be defined for entire complex plane?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Can the von-Mangoldt function and the Chebyshev function be defined for the entire complex plane ?

I assume so, but I had not seen the definition. Can anyone provide some links for this?

Thank you.

Comment: No. The von-Mangoldt function $\Lambda(n)$ is defined only on the positive integers, and it makes no sense to try to define it for the entire complex plane. The Chebyshev functions $\psi(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n)$ and $\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \log p$ are defined for positive real numbers $x$, and constant almost everywhere apart from jump discontinuities at prime powers (for $\psi(x)$) or primes (for $\vartheta(x)$). Again, it makes no sense to try to extend these to functions on the complex numbers.

Comment: @PeterHumphries yes and no, remember the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ can be obtained by writing $x-\lfloor x\rfloor - 1/2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} Im(\log(1-e^{2 i \pi x}))$ and using it as some sort of "analytic continuation" of $x-\lfloor x\rfloor - 1/2$

Comment: (the idea being that $\Gamma(s) \zeta(s+1) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_n \frac{e^{-nx}}{n}dx$ is just a change of contour of $\frac{\zeta(1-s)}{1-s}$ with $\frac{\zeta(s)}{s} = -\int_0^\infty (x-\lfloor x \rfloor-\frac{1}{2}) x^{-s-1}dx$ for $Re(s) \in (-1,0)$ )

Answer (score 0):

The von Mangoldt function can be generated at the pole $s=1$ of Riemann zeta with the formula:
$$\Lambda(n,s)=\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$$

So you can instead of $s \rightarrow 1$ let $s$ be complex number so that you have: $s=a+ib$

$$\Lambda(n,a,b)=\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow a+ib} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$$